# another java illegal state exception

Tags: java, android

I am reading my crash reports from google play developers and users heavy crashing on that error, i cant reproduce why it happens.

> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2820)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2895)   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11
>   (Unknown Source)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1596)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:105)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6565)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (Zygote.java:240)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:767)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:    at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:986)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.au.onCreate (SupportActivity.java:66)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.j.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:285)   at
>   android.support.v7.app.e.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:84)   at
>   com.generalmobile.app.musicplayer.PlayerActivity.onCreate
>   (PlayerActivity.java:78)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate
>   (Activity.java:6975)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
>   (Instrumentation.java:1214)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2773)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//line78    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

it happened after minor update,  dont know how savedInstanceState affected

Comment: Refer line num 78 of your PlayerActivity

Comment: refer this https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalStateException to know why its occurs.

Comment: add your `PlayerActivity` snippet containing the line number 78

Comment: this is line 78 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); rgiht after oncreate method

Comment: post the code of PlayerActivity class

Comment: very mixed code and project

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        init();
    }